# 'cpp' v.s. 'clang' Preprocessing Behavior

Tags: gcc, clang, c-preprocessor, preprocessor

*a.txt*

```
a text
#include "b.txt"
```

*b.txt*

```
b text
```

---

If we pre-process the above files using `cpp -P a.txt`, we get the following output in the console:

```
a text
b text
```

However if we attempt to pre-process using `clang -P a.txt`, we receive the following error:

```
ld: unknown file type in '/Users/myUser/a.txt'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What is the difference between the pre-processing behavior of `clang` and `cpp`? Particularly, what is their difference in this use case of .txt files? [Seemingly related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43967458/difference-between-cpp-and-gcc-e), as well as [another](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/467668/502004) specified to MacOS.

Comment: `cpp`  is a preprocessor. `clang` is a compiler. Both accept a `-P` option (which tells the preprocessor not to emit line directives), but you need to use `clang -E` to tell it to invoke only the preprocessor. I'm not posting this as an answer because `clang -E -P a.txt` doesn't work as expected on my system; it complains about "linker input". If I rename the file to `a.c` it works pretty much as expected.

Comment: thanks, i did not know i needed to first `-E` for `clang`. I found in the [cpp manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Overview.html) it says "in the past, [cpp] has been abused as a general text processor. It will choke on input which does not obey C’s lexical rules". I wonder how this is related

Comment: That's not related in this case, but for example a lone apostrophe might cause `cpp` to fail because it sees it as an incomplete character constant. `clang` is similar to `gcc`; both are compilers (or compiler drivers) and both take a `-E` option to invoke just the preprocessor. But both assume that an input file whose name ends with `.txt` is meant for the linker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cpp` is a preprocessor. `clang` is a compiler that may invoke a preprocessor before compiling its input files. You can't just use them with the same command-line options.

`clang` is similar to `gcc`. Both take a `-E` option to invoke just the preprocessing phase -- and both assume that an input file whose name ends with `.txt` is intended for the linker.

The following works on my system. The `-` argument tells the command to read from stdin, so it doesn't see the `.txt` suffix.

(Or you can use `-xc` or `-x c` to tell the compiler to assume that the input file is C source, regardless of the file name. Thanks to
KamilCuk for reminding me of this.)

```
$ cat a.txt
a text
#include "b.txt"
$ cat b.txt 
b text
$ gcc -P -E - < a.txt 
a text
b text
$ clang -P -E - < a.txt
a text
b text

$
```

The preprocessor used by `clang` adds an extra blank line. Since the output is intended to be compiled, usually as C or C++, this usually doesn't matter.

The C preprocessor isn't really a general-purpose text processor. For example, it splits its input into *preprocessing tokens*, so a lone apostrophe is likely to cause an error as the preprocessor treats it as an incomplete character constant.

Comment: Use `-xc` to set the file type to C when working with files with different extensions.