# What does these few lines do as a small test framework in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

Hi I am reading through the implementation of `std::optional` [here](https://github.com/akrzemi1/Optional/blob/master/test_optional.cpp) and I found the following lines in its unit testing files.

```
struct caller {
    template <class T> caller(T fun) { fun(); }
};
# define CAT2(X, Y) X ## Y
# define CAT(X, Y) CAT2(X, Y)
# define TEST(NAME) caller CAT(__VAR, __LINE__) = []
```

I don't really understand what do these lines do. `caller` seems to be a template to invoke functions, but how can it be used as `caller CAT ...`?
What does `X ## Y` mean here? Later in the file, the user define unit tests using `TEST`, but they do not appear in any executable code (I mean they are not called in `main` function at least), so I am not even sure if the compiled binary actually run the tests. Could you explain what is going on here? Thanks!

Edit: pretty sure the tests are executed when I run the binary, but how is that achieved?

Comment: It's interesting that the definition of macro `TEST(NAME)` doesn't use the `NAME` parameter.  I'm guessing that's a mistake.  You might also want to include an example of those the macro(s) are used.

Comment: @MichaelBurr thanks for mentioning it. That is one of my questions as well. I forgot to put it in.

Comment: the `CAT` and `CAT2` macros are [concatenating their token arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1489985/4892076).

Comment: and `TEST` is used like so: `TEST(testname){}`

Comment: If you use Eclipse, it has a feature whereby you can see macro expansions and how they are extended, step by step, Netbeans has a macro expansion view, but just the final output.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can look at the output after the preprocessing ( `-E` for gcc)...

This is the code where I added a usage of the macro:

```
struct caller {
    template <class T> caller(T fun) { fun(); }
};
# define CAT2(X, Y) X ## Y
# define CAT(X, Y) CAT2(X, Y)
# define TEST(NAME) caller CAT(__VAR, __LINE__) = []

TEST(disengaged_ctor) { foo(); };
```

[after preprocessing the last line turns to:](https://godbolt.org/g/3CveE8)

```
caller __VAR10 = []{ foo(); };
```

I am a bit puzzled about the `__VAR` and the unused `NAME` *. However, `[]{ foo(); }` is a lambda that when used to create a `caller` gets invoked in the `caller`s constructor.

* = I guess the idea is the following: Suppose you get a error message saying there is an error in `__VAR10` then on line `10` you find `TEST(disengaged_ctor)`, ie. the `NAME` of the failed test.

Comment: @EdgarRokyan yeah I think the important part is just to give them unique names and this is assured by using the line number

Comment: After looking through the code I think exactly the same.

Comment: It took me a little more thought to realize that the functions are run when the global `__VARxx` objects are constructed.  Clever.

Comment: @MichaelBurr yeah its one of the quite rare really nice usages of macros