# Compiling a fortran90 files with different parameters each time

Tags: shell, fortran, sh, fortran90, intel-fortran

I am recently working on a fortran90 program which calculate the time needed and result of some mathematics calculation. Here is the code:

```
program loops 

  use omp_lib 

  implicit none 
  integer, parameter :: N=729
  integer, parameter :: reps=1000


  real(kind=8), allocatable ::  a(:,:), b(:,:), c(:) 
  integer :: jmax(N)  


  real(kind=8) :: start1,start2,end1,end2
  integer :: r

  allocate(a(N,N), b(N,N), c(N))  

  call init1()  

  start1 = omp_get_wtime()

  do r = 1,reps
     call loop1() 
  end do

  end1  = omp_get_wtime()  

  call valid1(); 

  print *, "Total time for ",reps," reps of loop 1 = ", end1-start1 

  call init2()  

  start2 = omp_get_wtime()

  do r = 1,reps
     call loop2() 
  end do

  end2  = omp_get_wtime()  

  call valid2(); 

  print *, "Total time for ",reps," reps of loop 2 = ", end2-start2 


contains 

subroutine init1()

  implicit none 

  integer ::  i,j

  do i = 1,N 
     do j = 1,N 
        a(j,i) = 0.0 
        b(j,i) = 3.142*(i+j)
     end do
  end do

end subroutine init1 


subroutine init2()

  implicit none 

  integer ::  i,j,expr

  do i = 1,N 
     expr = mod(i,3*(i/30)+1)
     if (expr == 0) then
        jmax(i) = N 
     else
        jmax(i) = 1
     end if
     c(i) = 0.0 
  end do

  do i = 1,N 
     do j = 1,N 
        b(j,i) = dble(i*j+1)/dble(N*N)
     end do
  end do

end subroutine init2


subroutine loop1() 

  implicit none 

  integer ::  i,j
  !$OMP PARALLEL DO DEFAULT(NONE), PRIVATE(i,j), SHARED(a,b), SCHEDULE(type,chunksize) 
  do i = 1,N
     do j = N,i,-1
        a(j,i) = a(j,i) + cos(b(j,i))
     end do
  end do
  !$OMP END PARALLEL DO

end subroutine loop1 



subroutine loop2() 

  implicit none 

  integer :: i,j,k
  real (kind=8) :: rN2  

  rN2 = 1.0 / dble (N*N)  

  !$OMP PARALLEL DO DEFAULT(NONE), PRIVATE(i,j,k), SHARED(rN2,c,b,jmax), SCHEDULE(type,chunksize)
  do i = 1,N
     do j = 1, jmax(i) 
        do k = 1,j 
           c(i) = c(i) + k * log(b(j,i)) *rN2
        end do
     end do
  end do
  !$OMP END PARALLEL DO

end subroutine loop2



subroutine valid1()

  implicit none 

  integer :: i,j 
  real (kind=8) :: suma 

  suma= 0.0

  do i = 1,N 
     do j = 1,N 
        suma = suma + a(j,i) 
     end do
  end do

  print *, "Loop 1 check: Sum of a is ", suma

end subroutine valid1



subroutine valid2()

  implicit none 

  integer i 
  real (kind=8) sumc 

  sumc= 0.0
  do i = 1,N 
     sumc = sumc + c(i) 
  end do

  print *, "Loop 2 check: Sum of c is ", sumc

end subroutine valid2  


end program loops
```

In the line `!$OMP PARALLEL DO DEFAULT(NONE), PRIVATE(i,j), SHARED(a,b), SCHEDULE(type,chunksize)` and `!$OMP PARALLEL DO DEFAULT(NONE), PRIVATE(i,j,k), SHARED(rN2,c,b,jmax), SCHEDULE(type,chunksize)`.

As I want to perform the task of different schedule case to see the different results, so I need to change this part `SCHEDULE(type,chunksize)`, with different schedule type and different chunksize. For example, in this case, the schedule type is static and chunksize is 1.

Say if I have type of (static, a, b, c) and chunksize (1,2,3,4,5,6,7). As I am new to fortran so I wonder is it possible to compile and run the code for all case in once without the fact that I have to change the parameters manually everytime, i.e it compiles and runs to give the result of first case e.g (static,1), it then compiles and runs the file again but with the parameters changed automatically that gives another result. For instance, (static,2)...(b,4) etc.

I heard that we can create a script file to perform such task, but I not am sure what exactly I need to do for this.

Thank you so much.

Comment: OpenMP provides a `runtime` schedule which seems to be exactly what you want.  You can manipulate it using the function `omp_set_schedule` or using an environment variable `omp_schedule`.  Look hard enough and you'll even find examples here on SO.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to investigate the use of the preprocessor.  I'm speaking from experience with gfortran, but I believe this applies (almost) all other compilers as well even though it is outside the scope of the Fortran standard.

If you name your source file with a capital F in the suffix, i.e. file.F, file.F90, file.F95 etc, your file will be preprocessed with the C preprocessor before being compiled.  That may sound complicated, but cutting this down to what you need, this means that if you compile your code with a command like

```
$ gfortran -DCHUNK_SIZE=1 mySource.F90
```

then all occurrences of `CHUNK_SIZE` (with qualifiers which are not essential to your problem) will be replaced by `1`.  More technically, `CHUNK_SIZE` becomes a macro defined to expand to `1`.  So if you replace `SCHEDULE(type,chunksize)` with `SCHEDULE(type,CHUNK_SIZE)` in your source file, you can repeatedly invoke the compiler with different values, `-DCHUNK_SIZE=1`, `-DCHUNK_SIZE=2` etc, and get the result that you described.  The same can be done for `type`.

Now you may want to change the function names accordingly as well.  One way would be to add a few preprocessor statements near the top of your file declaring a few macros, namely

```
#ifdef __GFORTRAN__
#define PASTE2(a,b) a/**/b
#define FUNC_NAME_WITH_CHUNK_SIZE(fn) PASTE2(PASTE2(fn,_),CHUNK_SIZE)
#else
#define FUNC_NAME_WITH_CHUNK_SIZE(fn) fn ## _ ## CHUNK_SIZE
#endif
#define LOOP1 FUNC_NAME_WITH_CHUNK_SIZE(loop1)
#define LOOP2 FUNC_NAME_WITH_CHUNK_SIZE(loop2)
```

and replace `loop1` with `LOOP1` etc.  You could do this from the command line as before, but since these rules are not supposed to change between compilations, it makes sense to keep these in the source file.  I think the only part that is not self-explanatory is the use of `##` and `/**/` between `#ifdef` and `#endif`.  This is how one does string concatenation with the preprocessor, and because gfortran uses the way C preprocessors did it before the language was standardized, it gets exceptional treatment, see e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489932/how-to-concatenate-twice-with-the-c-preprocessor-and-expand-a-macro-as-in-arg/1489985#1489985) for some info on these operators.  The purpose of this operation is to replace `LOOP1` with `loop1_<CHUNK_SIZE>`, where `<CHUNK_SIZE>` is filled in from the command line.  Feel free to follow any other conventions for naming these functions.

If you want to call these functions from another translation unit, you will have to process the function names in the same way, of course.  In order to make your life easier, you may want to research the `#include` statement.  Detailing this would take us too far here, but the idea is that you put all your includes into a file (conventionally named `<something>.inc` in the Fortran-world with `<something>` replaced that makes sense to you) and use `#include "<something>.inc` in all source files to obtain the same macro definitions.

Comment: Not all compilers use a C preprocessor, Intel Fortran for example has a dedicated Fortran preprocessor which is slightly different to the C preprocessor.

Comment: Actually, it works with Intel, not gfortran. I misremembered. gfortran uses the "traditional" mode for the preprocessor to avoid the differences between standard C tokenization and Fortran's rules. I'm adapting the examples accordingly.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes, from Fortran 2003 onwards. See get_command_argument and related.

Comment: @Mad Physicist: Ian Bush ist of course correct, but to be clear, the flags I'm talking about are used at compile-time, so they are not consumed by a Fortran program, they are used to compile a Fortran program differently.