# how to define duplicated two function with one copy of code in c

Tags: c, duplicates, macros, arm

I need two same functions to map to two cores itcm in arm, in a way I can define two function
as below

```
#pragma arm section code="core0itcm"
void function1_core0()
{
  < program body xxx>
}
#pragma arm section code

..
#pragma arm section code="core1itcm"
void function1_core1()
{
    < program body xxx>
}
#pragma arm section code
```

But in this way, I have to manually maintain the same logic in two different location.

Is there an elegent way to define two function with same "progam body" ?
With inline or use advanced use of MACRO?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a macro with multiple lines, you have to use backslash-newline at the end of each line of your program body. See [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Object-like-Macros.html#Object-like-Macros).

```
#define PROGRAM_BODY \
line 1 \
line 2 \
... \
line n-1 \
line n

#pragma arm section code="core0itcm"
void function1_core0()
{
PROGRAM_BODY
}
#pragma arm section code
```

If you have much code then it may be better to put it in a separate include file. See [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Include-Syntax.html#Include-Syntax).

```
#pragma arm section code="core0itcm"
void function1_core0()
{
#include "program_body.h"
}
#pragma arm section code
```

Both isn't very good programming style but it uses the pre-processor to fill your `pragma` sections with explicit code.

**Update**

If you have multiple functions and want only one header file you can vary the core name by defining and redefining a macro:

```
#pragma arm section code="core0itcm"
#define CORE core0
#include "your_functions.h"
#pragma arm section code

#pragma arm section code="core1itcm"
#undef CORE
#define CORE core1
#include "your_functions.h"
#pragma arm section code
```

In `your_functions.h` you can use the macro like this:

```
#define PASTER(x,y) x ## _ ## y
#define CONCAT(x,y) PASTER(x,y)

void CONCAT(function1, CORE)()
{
  < program body 1>
}

void CONCAT(function2, CORE)()
{
  < program body 2>
}
```

Credits: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1489985/18667225

Comment: we have more than 30 function, to use option 2, we have to create seperate 30 header files.
these files will be hard to maintain ( in source insight ,  assert file line etc )

Is there other ways ?