# Use a macro to call a function from a string

Tags: c, macros

I have a series of functions that I need to call, and all the calls are of the form:

```
StartingFunctionName[Thing]Callback(&[Thing]);
```

Where `[Thing]` is the same thing each time
for example, I have to call

```
StartingFunctionNameMyFunctionCallback(&MyFunction);
```

and I'd like to rather do `foo(MyFunction);` where foo would be the macro.

I was wondering if there was a way to use a macro, so that its input is the string (or something like that) Thing, and the output is the correct line of code.

Comment: It's a bit hard to follow. Are you saying that the string contains the name of the function you want to call (or is part of the name of the function)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I concatenate twice with the C preprocessor and expand a macro as in "arg ## \_ ## MACRO"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489932/how-can-i-concatenate-twice-with-the-c-preprocessor-and-expand-a-macro-as-in-ar)

Comment: I tried to clarify my question, sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: I'd probably write a function (which can be inlined) instead of a macro.   Bit hard to know from your example (too many of the parts of your example are unspecified).

Answer (score 2):

If this is your pattern:

```
StartingFunctionName[Thing]Callback(&[Thing]);
```

and you want the token 'Thing' replaced, then via function like macro:

```
#define foo(Thing) \
    StartingFunctionName##Thing##Callback(&Thing)
```

**Example:**

```
foo(exit);
```

expands to

```
StartingFunctionNameexitCallback(&exit);
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer was to use the ##
`#define foo(thing) StartingFunctionName##thing(& thing)`