# C Programming: Preprocessor, macros as tokens

Tags: c, macros, token, c-preprocessor, stringification

I'm trying to do something that is conceptually similar to this, but can't seem to get it to work (error shown at end) any ideas?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc , char const *argv[] )
{
  int abc_def_ghi = 42;
  #define SUFFIX ghi
  #define VAR(prefix) prefix##_def_##SUFFIX
  printf( "%d\n" , VAR(abc) );
  return 0;
}

// untitled:8: error: ‘abc_def_SUFFIX’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

Comment: `const argv`? First time I see such a thing! The idea seems nice, but I'm not sure I like it: it makes `main` non-conformant and prevents me from doing something I never did ;)

Comment: It's not non-conformant.  `argv` can be declared as something equivalent to `char* argv[]` (C99 5.1.2.2.1), and adding the `const` there doesn't change anything except what `main()` is allowed to do with it (without a cast).  Remember that a pointer to a non-const can be converted to a pointer to a const no problem - right down to the fact that values of those pointers will compare equal (6.3.2.3/2).

Comment: Right, thanks Michael. It's the other way around (removing `const`) that would make it non-conformant. I'm beginning to like it!

Comment: Hi, sorry for that distraction, I should have taken that out. When using TextMate, typing main followed by tab fills out a scaffold for the main method, and that is part of it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just need additional indirection:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc , char const *argv[] )
{
  int abc_def_ghi = 42;
  #define SUFFIX ghi
  #define VAR3(prefix, suffix) prefix##_def_##suffix
  #define VAR2(prefix, suffix) VAR3(prefix, suffix)
  #define VAR(prefix) VAR2(prefix, SUFFIX)
  printf( "%d\n" , VAR(abc) );
  return 0;
}
```

Even though it looks redundant, it's not.

Comment: It's a bit too late for me to try and understand the Standardese for `6.10.3.3 The ## operator`, but it explains why somewhere there. ( pdf @ http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1401.pdf )

Comment: Because the replacement list of a macro is not itself subject to macro-replacement before its parameters are replaced and # and ## operators applied. So in the questioner's code, `def_##SUFFIX` is replaced with `def_SUFFIX` before any opportunity to replace `SUFFIX` with `ghi`. In caf's code, when `suffix` is replaced by `SUFFIX` in VAR2, the argument is first subject to macro expansion (6.10.3.1/1). The result is `VAR3(abc,ghi)`, which yields `abc_def_ghi`. Note that `VAR3(abc,SUFFIX)` would still give `abc_def_SUFFIX`, because parameters following ## are not expanded (also 6.10.2.1/1).

Comment: "(also 6.10.2.1/1)" - I mean "(also 6.10.3.1/1)".

Answer (score 7):

The usual idiom for correctly using the stringizing (`#`) or token pasting (`##`) pre-processing operators is to use a 2nd level of indirection. ([What are the applications of the ## preprocessor operator and gotchas to consider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216875/in-macros/217181#217181)).

```
#define STRINGIFY2( x) #x
#define STRINGIFY(x) STRINGIFY2(x)

#define PASTE2( a, b) a##b
#define PASTE( a, b) PASTE2( a, b)
```

Then:

```
int main( int argc , char const *argv[] )
{
  int abc_def_ghi = 42;
  #define SUFFIX ghi
  #define VAR(prefix) PASTE( prefix, PASTE( _def_, SUFFIX))
  printf( "%d\n" , VAR(abc) );
  return 0;
}
```

Should give you the results you're looking for.

Basically, what happens is that processing of the `#` and `##` operators takes place before macro replacement.  Then another round of macro replacement occurs.  So if you want macros to be used along with those operations you have to use a 1st level that simply does the replacement - otherwise the stringizing or pasting happens first, and the macros aren't macros anymore- they're whatever the 1st round of stringizing/pasting produces.

To put it more directly - the first level of macro allows the macro parameters to be replaced, then the 2nd level of macro replacement does the stringify/token-pasting operation.

Comment: Wow, thank you, the STRINGIFY also solves another issue I've had.

Answer (score 0):

This works with sufficient levels of indirection.  While another answer is plenty adequate, I want offer this chunk of code as a demo:

```
#define SUFFIX ghi

#define VAR1(prefix) prefix##_def_##SUFFIX
VAR1(abc)

#define VAR2_(prefix, sfx) prefix##_def_##sfx
#define VAR2(prefix) VAR2_(prefix,SUFFIX)
VAR2(abc)

#define VAR3_(prefix, sfx) prefix##_def_##sfx
#define VAR3x(prefix,sfx) VAR3_(prefix,sfx)
#define VAR3(prefix) VAR3x(prefix,SUFFIX)
VAR3(abc)
```

Save this is a text file, x.c, and only preprocess it.

```
gcc -E x.c
```

Observe and ponder.  I don't quite understand it entirely myself.  Just spend two hours trying to get a macro using stringify to work.  It is interesting to see that double indirection is sometimes needed.

Comment: I get
abc_def_SUFFIX
abc_def_SUFFIX
abc_def_ghi

Based on Steve's explanation, it sounds like it has to do with the order of macro replacement.