# How to use #if inside #define in the C preprocessor?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I want to write a macro that spits out code based on the boolean value of its parameter. So say `DEF_CONST(true)` should be expanded into `const`, and `DEF_CONST(false)` should be expanded into nothing.

Clearly the following doesn't work because we can't use another preprocessor inside #defines:

```
#define DEF_CONST(b_const) \
#if (b_const) \
  const \
#endif
```

Comment: What is the point of this? Do you have a concrete example, because this seems rather strange...

Comment: See also <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8427963/if-inside-define>.

Comment: @DeanHarding Didn't exist at the time of your comment, but `_Generic` is an example. You may need to check if `uintmax_t` has a different underlying type than `unsigned long long`.

Answer (score 68):

You can simulate conditionals using [macro token concatenation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Token_concatenation) as follows:

```
#define DEF_CONST(b_const) DEF_CONST_##b_const
#define DEF_CONST_true const
#define DEF_CONST_false
```

Then,

```
/* OK */
DEF_CONST(true)  int x;  /* expands to const int x */
DEF_CONST(false) int y;  /* expands to int y */

/* NOT OK */
bool bSomeBool = true;       // technically not C :)
DEF_CONST(bSomeBool) int z;  /* error: preprocessor does not know the value
                                of bSomeBool */
```

Also, allowing for passing macro parameters to DEF_CONST itself (as correctly pointed out by GMan and others):

```
#define DEF_CONST2(b_const) DEF_CONST_##b_const
#define DEF_CONST(b_const) DEF_CONST2(b_const)
#define DEF_CONST_true const
#define DEF_CONST_false

#define b true
#define c false

/* OK */
DEF_CONST(b) int x;     /* expands to const int x */
DEF_CONST(c) int y;     /* expands to int y */
DEF_CONST(true) int z;  /* expands to const int z */
```

You may also consider the much simpler (though potentially less flexible):

```
#if b_const
# define DEF_CONST const
#else /*b_const*/
# define DEF_CONST
#endif /*b_const*/
```

Comment: Typo in the above, just missed the edit mark. Should be `#define DEF_CONST(b_const) CONCATENATE(DEF_CONST_, b_const)`.

Comment: Yup - token pasting or stringizing ('`##`' or '`#`') preprocessor operators almost always really need a level of indirection to work as desired: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767683/c-programming-preprocessor-macros-as-tokens/1769037#1769037

Comment: Possible to expand this so it takes parameter as one would use in x macro?

Answer (score 8):

Doing it as a paramterised macro is a bit odd.

Why not just do something like this:

```
#ifdef USE_CONST
    #define MYCONST const
#else
    #define MYCONST
#endif
```

Then you can write code like this:

```
MYCONST int x = 1;
MYCONST char* foo = "bar";
```

and if you compile with `USE_CONST` defined (e.g. typically something `-DUSE_CONST` in the makefile or compiler options) then it will use the consts, otherwise it won't.

**Edit:** Actually I see Vlad covered that option at the end of his answer, so +1 for him :)