# preprocessor directives inside define?

Tags: c-preprocessor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C preprocessor: using #if inside #define?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831934/c-preprocessor-using-if-inside-define)

Is there any trick to have preprocessor directives inside rhs of define ? The problem is, preprocessor folds all rhs into one long line. But maybe there is a trick ?

Example of what I'd want in the rhs is

```
#define MY_CHECK \
  #ifndef MY_DEF  \
  # error MY_DEF not defined  \
  #endif
```

?
The purpose is a shortness: to have 1-line shortcut instead of multiline sequence of checks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As others have noted, preprocessor macros cannot expand into any other preprocessor directives; if they do you'll generally get odd errors about stray '#' characters in the input.  However, sometimes there are things you can do to get what you want.  If you want a macro that expands to something like:

```
#ifdef SOMETHING
...some code...
#endif
```

where *some code* doesn't include any preprocessor directives, you can define an IFDEF macro:

```
#ifdef SOMETHING
#define IFDEF_SOMETHING(X) X
#else
#define IFDEF_SOMETHING(X)
#endif
```

and then use `IFDEF_SOMETHING(...some code...)` in your other macro.

If you have a bunch of preprocessor cruft that you want to repeat multiple times, you can stick it in its own file and then use `#include "stuff"` in each spot you need it.

Comment: ... _some code_ had better not have any commas either.

Comment: @John: yes, though with C99 you can use `...`/`__VA_ARGS__` to avoid that problem

Comment: putting sequence of preprocessor directives in separate .h file and including it is good idea.

Answer (score 5):

It won't work (§6.10.3.4/3: "The resulting completely macro-replaced preprocessing token sequence is not processed as a preprocessing directive even if it resembles one ...").

If you *really* want to do things like this, you can run your source through something like m4 before compilation -- but I'd generally recommend against it.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming a preprocessor like the [GNU C Preprocessor](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/), then no. [The manual says](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Tokenization.html#Tokenization):

> The compiler does not re-tokenize the preprocessor's output. Each preprocessing token becomes one compiler token.