# #if inside #define?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I'm sitting on some legacy code that generates a lot of code through #defines. Now I know it's not possible to have an `#ifdef` inside a `#define`, but is an `#if` possible? I would like to do add some specialization for a specific type. (without making major changes like using templates instead). The following sample gives me cryptic errors so this is not the way:

```
#define MK_GET(type) \
  type get_ ## type (int index) \
  { \
    #if type == double \  <-- what i want to add
      specialized code... \
    #endif
    ...
  } \

MK_GET(double);
MK_GET(int);
MK_GET(string);
```

Comment: An `#ifdef` is just a shorter way of saying `#if defined(...)`, so I would say it's not possible.

Comment: See also <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831934/c-preprocessor-using-if-inside-define>.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could achieve that with templates:

```
template<typename T>
struct getter
{
    T operator()(int index)
    {
        // general code
    }
};

template<>
struct getter<double>
{
    T operator()(int index)
    {
        // specialized code
    }
};

#define CAT(a, b) a ## b
#define MK_GET(type) type CAT(get_, type) (int index) getter<type>()(index)
```

Comment: This! Generally, many larger #define's can be reduced to a template and small defines. You'll thank me when having to debug it.

Comment: This is a good way, thanx. It never occured to me i could use smaller template snippetes without changing the whole #define structures in the program :)

Answer (score 2):

The pre-processor is one pass process, so you can't place macro defines inside of macro defines. The only way to do this is via the template interface.

Answer (score 0):

Why you dont write it like this:

```
#if (type == double)
    #define MK_GET  some code
#else
    #define MK_GET  same code with changes
#endif
```

Comment: Because then you can only have one define per module and you cannot generate code for all types in one module...

Answer (score 0):

`#if` cannot be nested inside `#define`. Why you want to avoid `template`s when that is the better choice. They are safe and "compilable" (not preprocessed).

Comment: Yes ofcrouse. But i dont want to make too big changes to running production code for a small fix.

Comment: They actually can...you just have to run the preprocessor more than once (in fact, once for each nesting level).  It's a stupid thing to do, but it can be done.  See, for instance, the vik2 entry in the international obfuscated c code contest from 2004 (http://www.ioccc.org/years.html#2004) and it's associated Makefile