# Can I conditionally replace preprocessor arguments?

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

Working with a unit test framework, I came across a situation in which I'd like to test macro arguments. Simply said, I'd like to expand the macro `FOO(x)` such that `FOO(int)` would be `short` and `FOO(anything_else)` would be `long`.

With C++ templates, of course this isn't a problem. But here I need a real token replacement, not just a `typedef`. I.e. `FOO(char) FOO(char) i;` should be a valid definition equal to `long long i;`.

Comment: The newest C standard has feature where the replacement text of a macro can depend on the expression type of the first argument. You could use this as a building block.

Comment: Did you have a look at boost.pp and if you can hack somethign together with it?

Comment: @StefanMajewsky: You're referring to Generics I believe?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, the only string-like operations available in C macros are pasting/concatenating tokens (using `##`), and string-izing them (using `#`).

I'm pretty sure the closest you're going to get involves enumerating the possibilities like so:

```
#define FOO(x) FOO__##x
#define FOO__int   short
#define FOO__short long
#define FOO__long  long
#define FOO__char  long
// ... for each type you want to replace
```

---

Inspiration from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831934/c-preprocessor-using-if-inside-define).

Comment: (Edit #2): if you have limited and known set of "elses", one could list them all.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that just now, and cleaned up the whole post.

Comment: I don't think I can enumerate my arguments up front; I might get a `FOO(AcmeWidgetUnitTest17)` :(

Answer (score 0):

what you are trying to do is impossible.

Macros are evaluated by the c preprocessor, which as the name implies runs before the compiler  runs. It doesn't know what the types of your symbols are yet.

Why don't you create a class for the type that casts itself to the right thing at the time it is evaluated by the compiler.

Comment: I don't care about types. I know that `int` at the preprocessing stage is just a token. Still, I want to act conditionally on the token `int`.