# Substitute expression by value?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I have the following macro:

```
#define REFLECTABLE(...) \
REFLECTABLE_CONST(BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SIZE(__VA_ARGS__)==0, __VA_ARGS__)
```

I ran the pre-processor. It passes to `REFLECTABLE_CONST` `3==0` instead of `0` or `false`. In `REFLECTABLE_CONST`, I am using that value to simulate a conditional as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2831966/2725810) post. So, I need the pre-processor to pass a value. Is there a way to make pre-processor substitute things like `3==0` by `false` or `0`?

Comment: No, the preprocessor is a text substitution mechanism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't reproduce `BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SIZE` being able to have a result of `0`, but if you can, this should work:

```
#define IS_EMPTY_IMPL0 1
#define IS_EMPTY_IMPL1 0
#define IS_EMPTY_IMPL2 0
#define IS_EMPTY_IMPL3 0
#define IS_EMPTY_IMPL4 0
#define IS_EMPTY_IMPL5 0
#define IS_EMPTY_IMPL6 0
#define IS_EMPTY_IMPL7 0
#define IS_EMPTY_IMPL8 0
#define IS_EMPTY_IMPL9 0

#define IS_EMPTY(...) BOOST_PP_CAT(IS_EMPTY_IMPL, BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SIZE(__VA_ARGS__))

#define REFLECTABLE(...) \
REFLECTABLE_CONST(IS_EMPTY(__VA_ARGS__), __VA_ARGS__)
```

Comment: **For a future visitor:** I accepted this reply, because it handles the question as is. However, see my own answer, which provides a simpler solution to the actual problem.

Answer (score 2):

Stumbled upon this solution. Just use this instead:

```
#define REFLECTABLE(...) \
REFLECTABLE_CONST(BOOST_PP_IS_EMPTY(__VA_ARGS__), __VA_ARGS__)
```

Comment: This macro doesn't seem to be documented on the Boost website.

Comment: **For a future visitor**: Look up http://stackoverflow.com/a/34220519/2725810 for an application of this solution.