# Force Whitespace in C Macro?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, stringification

I've got the following Macro to define a new function following a special naming scheme:

```
#define CREATE_HOOK_STUB( func ) void ##func_STUB() { /* some code*/ }
```

However, the preprocessor always concatenates `void` and `##func_STUB` but I obviously want it to preserve the whitespace at that position.

I know that I could just prepend some string to `##func_STUB`, but this is not what I want.
How would I solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think what you really want is closer to:

```
#define CREATE_HOOK_STUB( func ) void func##_STUB() { /* some code*/ }
```

But you should also look at [this linked SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216875/in-macros/217181#217181) which has some additional details on the behavior of the token pasting operator:

> One thing to be aware of when you're using the token-paste ('##') or stringizing ('#') preprocessing operators is that you have to use an extra level of indirection for them to work properly in all cases.
>
> If you don't do this and the items passed to the token-pasting operator are macros themselves, you'll get results that are probably not what you want...

- link:  [What are the applications of the ## preprocessor operator and gotchas to consider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216875/in-macros/217181#217181)