# C macro to generate printf format string

Tags: c, macros, printf, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to write a Macro (using token concatenation) that returns format for printf?
E.g.

```
#define STR_FMT(x) ...code-here...
```

`STR_FMT(10)` expands to `"%10s"`

`STR_FMT(15)` expands to `"%15s"`

...
etc.

So that I can use this macro inside a printf:

```
printf(STR_FMT(10), "*");
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can, but I think it might be better to use the capability `printf()` has to specify the field size and/or precision dynamically:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // specify the field size dynamically
    printf( ":%*s:\n", 10, "*");
    printf( ":%*s:\n", 15, "*");

    // specify the precision dynamically
    printf( "%.*s\n", 10, "******************************************");
    printf( "%.*s\n", 15, "******************************************");

    return 0;
}
```

This has the advantage of not using the preprocessor and also will let you use variables or functions to specify the field width instead of literals.

---

If you do decide to use macros instead, please use the `#` operator indirectly (and the `##` operator if you use it elsewhere) like so:

```
// macros to allow safer use of the # and ## operators
#ifndef STRINGIFY
#define STRINGIFY2( x) #x
#define STRINGIFY(x) STRINGIFY2(x)
#endif

#define STR_FMTB(x) "%" STRINGIFY(x) "s"
```

Otherwise if you decide to use macros to specify the field width, you'll get undesired behavior (as described in [What are the applications of the ## preprocessor operator and gotchas to consider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216875/in-macros/217181#217181)).

Comment: +1 for mentioning `%*`, and figuring out that OP probably wants to pass variables and not compile-time constants to this macro.

Answer (score 7):

```
#define STR_FMT(x) "%" #x "s"
```

Comment: For future reference, gcc now flags this as a security warning. It's considered unsafe to construct a `printf` substitution using stringification, because mistakes in the macro argument result in binary code that is easily exploited by memory layout attacks.