# What do two adjacent pound signs mean in a C macro?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I'm taking a look at an application that defines a large set of constant arrays. What really confuses me is the use of two pound signs next to each other in a macro. For example:

```
#define r0(p,q,r,s) 0x##p##q##r##s
```

What do those two pound signs mean?

Comment: `#` = hash. `£` = pound sign.

Comment: @TRiG I'm not British... http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pound_sign

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the applications of the ## preprocessor operator and gotchas to consider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216875/what-are-the-applications-of-the-preprocessor-operator-and-gotchas-to-conside)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`##` provides a way to **[concatenate actual arguments](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html)** during macro expansion.

Comment: Link is dead, unfortunately.

Comment: @Neftas more like rotten.

Answer (score 10):

`##` concattenates symbols. So for example if the value of `p` is `ab`, `0x##p` would become `0xab`.

Answer (score 5):

Als and sepp2k give correct answer.

However I would like to add, that this macro seems to be completely unnecessary.

```
unsigned int value = r0(b,e,a,f);
```

can be replaced by better and shorter:

```
unsigned int value = 0xbeaf;
```

Comment: If it's being used as part of a larger macro, it would be cleaner to read `r0(p,q,r,s)` instead of `0x##p##q##r##s` all over the place.

Comment: @StilesCrisis: No, if it is used as part of a large macro, it would be cleaner to rewrite the code without any macros.

Comment: C is hardly a perfect language--sometimes a macro is still the best choice. Without knowing more about the OPs' code it's hard to say.