# String as macro with arguments in C

Tags: c, macros

Considering the following string:

```
Page 1 of 100
```

Where `1` and `100` are not fixed values.

How could I define a C macro in order to render that string by passing the two values as arguments?

To be clear, the format has to be as follows:

```
#define PAGE_IDX_MACRO(x,y)
```

Comment: And since you said "string", even if you didn't use quotes: Look up the stringize operator.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `#` operator converts a preprocessor token to a string literal.

String literals are concatenated in C by simply adding a space between them, i.e `"hello" "world"` is equivalent to `"helloworld"`.

So the macro should be:

```
#define PAGE_IDX_MACRO(x, n) ("Page " #x " of " #n)
```

Assuming it is called like this:

```
PAGE_IDX_MACRO(1, 100);
```

Where 1 and 100 are compile-time constants.

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate strings via the double hash tag:

> `##` provides a way to **[concatenate actual arguments][1]** during
>   macro expansion.
>
> [1]:
>   http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v7v91/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.vacpp7a.doc/language/ref/clrc09numnum.htm

from this question:

[What do two adjacent pound signs mean in a C macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9059772/3045049)

Comment: Although I'm not sure this is realy needed here -- `#define PAGE_IDX_MACRO(x,y) Page x of y` should do, possibly stringized, probably by using another preprocessor indirection. I think nothing is really concatenated here.