# Using C preprocessor concatenation to get number in exponential notation

Tags: concatenation, c-preprocessor

Why does code:

```
#define EXPONENT(num, exp) num ## e ## exp
EXPONENT(1,1)
EXPONENT(1,-1)
EXPONENT(1,+1)
```

after preprocessing changes into:

```
1e1
1e- 1
1e+ 1
```

and not into

```
1e1
1e-1
1e+1
```

? 
I suspect it might be because -1,+1 are parsed as two tokens (?). However, how in that case obtain the latter result?

Comment: I think you need another level of indirection... see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489932/c-preprocessor-and-concatenation

Comment: I think another level of indirection is necessary, when trying to concatenate with value of another #define, which is not the case here.

Comment: @JoSo: Hmm.  Doesn'tWorkForMe (GCC 4.1.2, 4.3.4 or 4.5.1)!

Comment: I've checked it with gcc 4.6.3 and clang 3.0

Comment: @KrzysztofWitkowski: Strange! Still researching.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Sorry for the noise, forgot to check with negative value.

Comment: This is indeed strange.  If the macro is just `e ## exp`, then no spaces appear.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/216975/195488

Answer (score 4):

You're right, `-1` and `+1` are two preprocessing tokens, hence only the first is pasted to the `e`.

For me,

```
#define EXPO(num, sign, ex) num ## e ## sign ## ex

EXPO(1,,1)
EXPO(1,-,1)
EXPO(1,+,1)
```

worked with gcc-4.5.1.

Comment: This works. However, to solve my problem you have changed its description ;-) I need a macro that takes only two arguments, number and exponent...

Comment: If that's an unchangeable requirement, I have no idea how to do it. It may be impossible.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem you are running into is considered undefined behavior. Per [gcc 4.3.2 documentation on concatentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.2/cpp/Concatenation.html):

> However, two tokens that don't together form a valid token cannot be
>   pasted together. For example, you cannot concatenate x with + in
>   either order. If you try, the preprocessor issues a warning and emits
>   the two tokens. Whether it puts white space between the tokens is
>   undefined. It is common to find unnecessary uses of ## in complex
>   macros. If you get this warning, it is likely that you can simply
>   remove the `##'.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/216975/195488) on SO which exhibits the same problem.

Edit:

I managed to get this to work, but you'll need two macros for + and -

```
#define E(X) 1e-##X
int main()
{
  double a = E(10); // expands to 1e-10
  printf("%e", a);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean that it is impossible to solve my problem with C preprocessor?

Comment: @kwitek: Did you try a variant of the last code sample in that answer?

Comment: Yes. #define EXPO(x, y) x e y leaves whitespaces, and #define EXPO(x, y) xeb results in string xeb ;(

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define EXPONENT(num, exp) atof(#num "e" #exp)

void main(){
    double x = EXPONENT(1,-1); 
    printf("%f", x);
}
```

Comment: I think Daniel's suggestion is better.