# What does ## (double hash) do in a preprocessor directive?

Tags: c++, c, concatenation, c-preprocessor

```
#define DEFINE_STAT(Stat) \
struct FThreadSafeStaticStat<FStat_##Stat> StatPtr_##Stat;
```

The above line is taken from Unreal 4, and I know I could ask it over on the unreal forums, but I think this is a general C++ question that warrants being asked here.

I understand the first line defines a macro, however I am not well versed in preprocessor shenanigans in C++ and so I'm lost over there. Logic tells me the backslash means the declaration continues onto the next line.

`FThreadSafeStaticStat` looks a bit like a template, but there's `#`'s going on in there and a syntax I've never seen before in C++.

Could someone tell me what this means? I understand that you may not have access to Unreal 4, but it's just the syntax I don't understand.

Comment: You can read about ## operator [on cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace#.23_and_.23.23_operators), among other things

Comment: `##` is/could be called the concatenation operator.

Comment: Oh, that's pretty cool! It explains rather a lot, thanks. But why is the struct keyword used? The line looks more like a variable definition

Comment: The `struct` introduces an *elaborate type specifier* as far as I can tell.

Comment: The official name is "token pasting operator" because it combines two preprocessing tokens to produce another.  Note that it is only valid if the result is a valid preprocessing token, e.g. you can't do `+ ## 3` to make `+3`. (But you can do `+ 3` of course, without the operator)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the applications of the ## preprocessor operator and gotchas to consider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216875/what-are-the-applications-of-the-preprocessor-operator-and-gotchas-to-conside)

Answer (score 230, accepted):

`##` is the preprocessor operator for concatenation.

So if you use

`DEFINE_STAT(foo)`

anywhere in the code, it gets replaced with

`struct FThreadSafeStaticStat<FStat_foo> StatPtr_foo;`

before your code is compiled.

Here is another example from [a blog post](https://susam.net/blog/obfuscated-main.html) of mine to explain this further.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define decode(s,t,u,m,p,e,d) m ## s ## u ## t
#define begin decode(a,n,i,m,a,t,e)

int begin()
{
    printf("Stumped?\n");
}
```

This program would compile and execute successfully, and produce the following output:

```
Stumped?
```

When the preprocessor is invoked on this code,

- `begin` is replaced with `decode(a,n,i,m,a,t,e)`
- `decode(a,n,i,m,a,t,e)` is replaced with `m ## a ## i ## n`
- `m ## a ## i ## n` is replaced with `main`

Thus effectively, `begin()` is replaced with `main()`.

Comment: Why `decode(a,n,i,m,a,t,e)` is replaced with `m ## a ## i ## n`? How is that??

Comment: The TL;DR of why the Stumped->Animate-> brain teaser works is that the function "decode" is set up as having the input "a", "n", "i", "m". These inputs are mapped to the *variables* "s", "t", "u", "m". These variables are then rearranged into the right order with the preprocessor string concatenation directive `m ## s ## u ## t` which takes the input "a", "n", "i", "m" and rearranges the characters to make the word "main" by changing the order of the *variables* "s", "t", "u", "m". I found it helpful to draw the the values and the variables and the mappings between them.

Answer (score 15):

TLDR; `##` is for concatenation and `#` is for stringification (from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace#.23_and_.23.23_operators)).

The `##` concatenates successive identifiers and it is useful when you want to pass a function as a parameter. Here is an example where `foo` accepts a function argument as its 1st argument and the operators `a` and `b` as the 2nd and 3rd arguments:

```
#include <stdio.h>
enum {my_sum=1, my_minus=2};
#define foo(which, a, b) which##x(a, b)
#define my_sumx(a, b) (a+b)
#define my_minusx(a, b) (a-b)

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int a = 2;
    int b = 3;
    printf("%d+%d=%d\n", a, b,  foo(my_sum, a, b));  // 2+3=5
    printf("%d-%d=%d\n", a, b, foo(my_minus, a, b)); // 2-3=-1
    return 0;
}
```

The `#` concatenates the parameter and encloses the output in quotes. The example is:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#define bar(...) puts(#__VA_ARGS__)
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    bar(1, "x", int); // 1, "x", int
    return 0;
}
```