# Generate identifier from macro parameter

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

I have macro in which i pass an argument:

```
#define bind(id) function[function_id::id] = std::bind(otherFunction::id, std::placeholders::_1)
```

In that case `id` expands to whatever I write into macro while using it. However I would like to add some characters to one of them, like this:

```
#define bind(id) function[function_id::id] = std::bind(otherFunction::add_id, std::placeholders::_1)
```

So that first replacement of `id` is original and second is with sufix `add_` . When I do that second expansion with `add_` won't expand, so I end up with `add_id` instead of `add_whatever_I_wanted`.

In that case I've tried to use brackets and write it like that:

```
#define bind(id) function[function_id::id] = std::bind(otherFunction::add_(id), std::placeholders::_1)
```

And it worked partially, now `id` is wrapped into brackets and expansion result is

```
add_(whatever_I_wanted)
```

Instead of

```
add_whatever_I_wanted
```

It's killing me as I want to use it quite often. Is there any workaround?

Comment: You'll have to use the string concatenation facilities of the preprocessor. Something along the lines of `other_function::STRCAT(add_, id)`. Please note that you'll have to define `STRCAT`.

Comment: You probably want `add_##id`. But if you want to pass another macro into `id` parameter, then you'll need several layers of indirection: something like `#define CAT(x,y) CAT_(x,y)` \n `#define CAT_(x,y) x##y` \n `... std::bind(otherFunction::CAT(add_,id) , ...`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22975073/what-does-double-hash-do-in-a-preprocessor-directive, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216875/what-are-the-applications-of-the-preprocessor-operator-and-gotchas-to-conside

Comment: Look up the token pasting capability  of the preprocessor using `##`.    I'd query using the processor at all though (for anything except including standard headers), as distinct from simply writing separate dedicated function to do what you need.   The preprocessor has a lot of down-sides, including not respecting scope.

Comment: Double hash worked like a charm. I was typing wrong questions into google therefore couldn't find satisfying topics on stack. Thanks!

Comment: FWIW, I strongly recommend avoiding macros whenever possible, even if it means increased code duplication (within reason). It's impossible to tell what a macro interacts with just by looking at its use, meaning that anyone else looking at your code is going to be confused. If you must use macros, the convention is to name them in `ALL_CAPS` to avoid some of the problems with name collisions (e.g. your macro cause problems if anyone wrote `std::bind(...)`, because that would expand the macro). In this case: `#define BIND(id) ...`

Comment: @Justin unfortuantely in this particular case I have to. However thank you for advice, I will change naming convention and try to avoid them in the future.

Comment: Somebody please make an answer to get this out of the list of unanswered questions.