# EEPROM write and read unknown directive

Tags: gcc, c-preprocessor, avr, eeprom, stringification

I have a problem with avr-gcc. 
I have an error recurring:

> **undefined reference to `__eerd_block'**

This is referred to a macro

**EELOAD(s)** and **EESAVE(s)** where s is a structure of uint, structs, eccc...

The define of **EELOAD(s)** and **EESAVE(s)** are:

```
#define EELOAD( s ) eeprom_read_block( &s, s##_eeprom, sizeof(s) )
#define EESAVE( s ) eeprom_write_block( &s, (void*) s##_eeprom, sizeof(s) )
```

I would like to know what is the `s##_eeprom`, or how the `##` is translated, it should be an address, but I can't figure out how can I modify or how to make work this.

Answer (score 1):

`##` is used to glue together two tokens. So `EELOAD(foo)` will get substituted to `eeprom_read_block(&foo, foo_eeprom, sizeof(foo))`. You'll find more information about ## here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216875/in-macros)
As for the macro itself, foo_eeprom should be a valid address from EEPROM space. You should have this defined somewhere for the code to compile.

Comment: Thanks very much, indeed was missing an include of the various foo_eeprom addresses. Now is compiling ,with other new errors, but that's another problem. Thank you mate, i can't vote u up sorry 'cause my rating too low, but u solved my problem.