# C Macro pound sign and plus sign

Tags: c

I was encountering the following code snippet. What does the double pound sign and plus sign mean here?

```
#define MPID_Get_ptr(kind,a,ptr)                    \
{                                                   \
   switch (HANDLE_GET_KIND(a)) {                    \
      case HANDLE_KIND_DIRECT:                      \
          ptr=MPID_##kind##_direct+HANDLE_INDEX(a);
```

Thanks,
Zack

Comment: possible duplicate of [## in Macros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216875/in-macros)

Answer (score 3):

It's the token pasting operator.

From [The C Programming language, 2nd edition, Kernighan & Ritchie](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/cbook/):

> "The preprocessor operator `##` provides a way to concatenate actual arguments during macro expansion. If a parameter in the replacement text is adjacent to a `##`, the parameter is replaced by the actual argument, the `##` and surrounding white space are removed, and the result is re-scanned. For example, the macro paste concatenates its two arguments:
>
> ```
> #define paste(front, back) front ## back
> ```
>
> so `paste(name, 1)` creates the token `name1`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation with ##. What does plus sign in the remaining part mean? Could you also explain that? Thanks.

Comment: It's a plus sign. It doesn't have any special meaning here, beyond addition.