# Preserving unreferenced locally allocated strings in C

Tags: c, compilation, c-preprocessor

I need an ability to create some string identifiers from inside the local scope of C functions, which will be placed by a linker to some not loadable section, or to a dedicated section that I could strip out without causing any failure to my program.

I have tried `#pragma ident “string”` or `#ident “string”`, both do the work, but my “string” parameter is generated by a macro and in fact after expansion it looks like `#pragma ident “string1” “string2”` and therefore only “string1” is being dumped into .comment section.

So what I need is a way to concatenate strings in pre-processing time to make it look like `#pragma ident “string1 string2”` or some other approach to preserve unreferenced strings in a dedicated section without generating extra code.

Comment: You can't use curly quotes in C code, they need to be `"`. Anyway, it sounds like you need to use the `##` string concatenation operator. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216875/in-macros

Comment: ## - doesn't concatenate strings, it concatenate parameters of a macro. "string1"##"string2" will cause a failure of pre-processor.

Comment: You said you need a way to concatenate strings in pre-processing time.

Comment: Correct, but at least one parameter of my macro will be inside quotes from the beginning, say CONCAT("string1", 5)

Comment: @pigeek: Is that unavoidable? Could you make it unquoted and stringify it when you need it quoted? Otherwise, I can't see any solution, although I don't want to say that it's impossible.

Comment: Please show more code, so we can see how you're trying to use this.