# Create object-like macro from concatenation of token and macro

Tags: c, concatenation, c-preprocessor

I want create an **object-like macro** from the concatenation of token and macro. I have this code:

```
#define alfa vita
/* Code below is broken. */
#define gamma delta##alfa
gamma
```

The `gamma` is replaced with `deltaalfa`. I want it replaced with `deltavita`. How can I do this?

I don't want the gamma to be a function-like macro.

---

[What are the applications of the ## preprocessor operator and gotchas to consider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216875/using-in-macros)
This question is very broad. It isn't focused on my problem and the first answer doesn't address it either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must perform a double macro expansion like so:

```
#define alfa vita

#define concat2(a,b) a ## b
#define concat(a,b) concat2(a,b)
#define gamma concat(delta, alfa)

gamma
```

The operands of the stringification (`#`) and token pasting (`##`) operators are not first expanded.  As a special case, expansion of a function-style macro proceeds by first expanding the arguments *except where they are operands of the `#` or `##` operator*, then substituting them into the macro body, then rescanning for substitutions.

The double-expansion approach above works because the arguments of the `concat()` macro are not operands of `##` (or `#`).  They are therefore expanded before being substituted into that macro's body to yield

```
concat2(delta, vita)
```

Upon rescanning, that is expanded further to

```
delta ## vita
```

(regardless of any macro definition for the symbol `vita`), which is then pasted together into a single token to yield the result.

Comment: This works in simple case. In my bigger code it doesn't. The `gamma` is expanded to `concat(delta, vita)` ...

Comment: You have left out the definition of the `concat()` macro, or misspelled `concat2` in its body.

Comment: I've added `#undef concat` after `#define gamma`. Now it works. Thank You.