# double scientific notation in macro

Tags: c, macros, double, notation

I was wondering if I can create macro that creating value with custom "shift" (or other way to create it in compile time). I mean, concatenate two numbers or something...

Something like that (of course it's not working):

```
#define CUSTOM_DOUBLE(shift) 1.05E shift
```

I know I can do:

```
#define CUSTOM_DOUBLE(shift) 1.05 * pow(10.0, shift)
```

But I'm aware that it isn't calculated in compile time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as `shift` argument is passed as *integer constant* (of decimal form) this can be accomplished by `##` operator, that concatenates preprocessing tokens. For instance, it may be implemented as:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define CUSTOM_DOUBLE(shift) (1.05E ## shift)

int main(void)
{
    double d = CUSTOM_DOUBLE(3);

    printf("%E\n", d);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You want this:

```
#define CUSTOM_DOUBLE(shift) 1.05E##shift
```

`##` is the [concatenation operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/216875/3425536).