# what is the meaning of make in c #define in dmlc code

Tags: c++

There is code in dmlc as below:

```
#define DMLC_REGISTRY_REGISTER(EntryType, EntryTypeName, Name)          \
  static EntryType & __make_ ## EntryTypeName ## _ ## Name ## __ =      \
      ::dmlc::Registry<EntryType>::Get()->__REGISTER__(#Name)           \
```

What is meaning of `__make_` in here? Contact with EntryTypeName and Name?
Any link will explain it?

What is the output about static EntryType & __make_ ## EntryTypeName ## _ ## Name ## __ =?

Comment: Do you know what `##` does in the C preprocessor? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216875/what-are-the-applications-of-the-preprocessor-operator-and-gotchas-to-conside

Comment: `__make_` is just a prefix being put onto all the names that get defined using the macro.

Comment: I don't think it particularly makes a difference to the question, but isn't this C++ rather than C?

Comment: Gah. Please don't write code like this outside your garage.