# How to Store size of a vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl, set, size

I want to store the size of a vector in a int any ways to do that or any way so that i can compare the size of vector with numbers ?

i.e

```
       int v3size = v3.size();
       if (v3size>1)
       <do something>
       else if (v3size==0)
       <do something>
```

Are there any ways to do something like this .

Answer (score 4):

It is not clear what problem you have. But in any case to store the size of a vector in a variable of type int will be incorrect because the size in class std:;vector has some unsigned integral type. So it would be better to write (let assume that the vector has type `std::vector<int>`)

```
std::vector<int>::size_type v3size = v3.size();

if ( v3size > 1 )
{
   //<do something>
}
else if ( v3size == 0 )
{
   //<do something> 
}
```

Comment: @cnluzon  Thanks. I also have seen this mistake and updated the post.:)

Comment: If you want to save the size of vector to a variable, then you should use one if type size_type or unsigned integer

Comment: @humam In general case using some unsigned type instead of size_type is also wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Look at [`size()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size) reference.

size() return type is:

```
size_type size() const;
```

`size_type` definition is [implementation dependent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226302/where-can-i-look-up-the-definition-of-size-type-for-vectors-in-the-c-stl), likely to be an integer.

BTW, yuor `else if (v3size=0)` should be `else if (v3size==0)`