# Scopeguard lifetime / pattern needed

Tags: c++, multithreading, design-patterns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [prohibiting instantiation as a temporary object (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588978/prohibiting-instantiation-as-a-temporary-object-c)

I use a Scopeguard  for locking like this (simplified):

```
{
ScopeGuard sg(mutex);
// ...critical code
}
```

I accidently typed in some place

```
{
ScopeGuard(mutex);
// ...critical code
}
```

which is valid code but does not extend the lifetime of the ScopeGuard object past the statement.

**Question:** Is there any pattern that will result in a compiler error or warning if I create a temporary ScopeGuard object like in the second example?

Answer (score 1):

I'd leverage the preprocessor to define a lock pseudo-keyword, as described here: http://www.curly-brace.com/lock.html

Comment: As it often happens with macros, the cure is worse than disease. Forgetfulness goes away with experience.

Comment: Granted - I avoid using macros myself. But if you cannot count on the experience of co-workers or library users, then they can help ensuring correct usage of code patterns.