# Preprocessor counter macro

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor, counter

Is there a way to create a `COUNTER()` macro (which follows the C++11/14 standard) that is expanded to a number which increases by one every time `COUNTER()` is invoked?

I've thought about it, but couldn't find a way to make it work. I didn't find a way to store "state" in the `COUNTER()` macro.

**Example:**

```
#define COUNTER() <...> // Implementation goes here...
#define UNIQUE_NAME_1() TEST ## COUNTER()
#define UNIQUE_NAME_2() TEST ## COUNTER()

// Note how the COUNTER() macro can be used with other macros
// (it cannot be implemented with C++ code)

int main() {
    std::cout << STRINGIFY(UNIQUE_NAME_1()) << std::endl;
    std::cout << STRINGIFY(UNIQUE_NAME_2()) << std::endl;
}
```

---

**Expected output:**

```
TEST0 
TEST1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GCC, and (I believe) VC++ both provide the `__COUNTER__` macro, which does about what you'd expect. I don't know that it follows the standard exactly, but it's probably close enough for real-world use.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/652815/has-anyone-ever-had-a-use-for-the-counter-pre-processor-macro has some nice coverage on this topic.