# Counter at Compile TIme

Tags: c++, templates, compile-time

I know this is a weird question, but I'm trying to find a way to analyze the code written by the user and collect some useful information that may be included in both "if" & "else" part. 
Suppose I have an if-else statement,

```
counter = 0;
if( true )
    ++counter;
else
    ++counter;
```

is it possible that I can "enforce ++counter" to work and get "counter = 2" at compiler time? Template? Macro? Any other solution? Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22332103/preprocessor-counter-macro

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `counter' will never be 2.  It will always be 1.

I'd say about 90% of current C++ compilers (running in "Release" mode") will recognize the invariant, and generate object code as if you had written:

```
counter = 0;
++counter;
```

Most will also go as far as

```
counter = 1;
```

However, such optimizations are not required by the Standard, so there is no way to "Force" a compiler to do them.

NOTE: The specifications for Java & C# *do* require compilers for those languages to recognize the invariant to do elide the `if()`)