# __COUNTER__ macro problems. Not displaying the value

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor, counter

I am trying to use the `__COUNTER__` macro to generate unique variable names in my code. But the macro doesn't seem to work. I may be using it the wrong way. Please provide me pointers or suggestion to what I am doing wrong.

`#define DUMB_MACRO() ht##__COUNTER__`

should give me ht0,ht1....

The way I am calling it in the main file is

`DUMB_MACRO();`

But the compiler says it doesn't resolve the symbol `ht__COUNTER__` if I try using `ht0` variable.

I also tried using the `__CONCAT` macro but I cannot pass variable into it.

For example:
`__CONCAT(ht,1)` works and gives me `ht1` but `__CONCAT(ht,i)` where `i` is a variable holding saying the value `1` doesn't work because its value is not known at compile time.

Comment: Be aware that `__COUNTER__` is a GNU extension; it's not necessarily portable to compilers other than g++ (clang++ seems to support it as well). (Unless it was added to the standard very recently).

Comment: It wasn't. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/652815/has-anyone-ever-had-a-use-for-the-counter-pre-processor-macro

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to expand the macro:

```
#define MACRO3(s) ht##s
#define MACRO2(s) MACRO3(s)
#define MACRO MACRO2(__COUNTER__)

int MACRO ;  //ht0
int MACRO ;  //ht1
```