# How to validate in gcc that variable is used with hton in certain function

Tags: c, validation, gcc, compilation, makefile

I defined uint16 variable.
I want to have a validation in compilation that whenever this variable is used, it must be first transformed with hton(). 
Is there a way to validate it during gcc compilation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a proper solution to this in C, as there is no way we can verify that a variable has changed byte order by going through `hton()`.

If somehow we are able to verify that, we could use a **static assert** (talked about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807244/c-compiler-asserts-how-to-implement) and [here](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/gcc/static_assert.html)) and create compile time checks.

You could still write a macro after the declaration of your variable `var`:

```
#define var hton(var)
```

This is probably a bad solution and could mess things up, so just use a function which returns the variable after running it through `hton()`.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, no, I don't believe.

I believe the proper solution to this is ordinary abstraction. Set up a file that contains your variable, together with getter and setter routines:

```
/* var.c */

static uint16_t my_hidden_var;

void set_hidden_var (uint16_t v) {
  my_hidden_var = v;
}

uint16_t get_hidden_var (void) {
  return htons (my_hidden_var);
}
```

Obviously that's a simplistic example, and you'd probably want to add more, but the point is that your access requirements are enforced.

---

If that's too heavyweight, I'd create a macro as the getter (an inline function would work fine too):

```
#define GET_VAR() htons (var)
```

Then, any mention of "var" in your sources must be either incorrect, or an exception to the rule, and you can find them easily with a simple text search.