# compile time bounding of template parameters in c++0x

Tags: templates, template-meta-programming, c++03

Here is a grossly over-simplified class:

```
template <unsigned x>
class myArray {
    int getIndex(unsigned i) { return y[i]; }
    void setIndex(unsigned i, int v) { y[i] = v; }
  private:
    int y[x];
};
```

How would I use template meta-programming to ensure `x` is less than `64` (*or any arbitrary value*)?

I could add the constructor:

```
myArray () { if (x >= 64) { throw; } }
```

but that is horrible...

Is there a more elegant way to bound the template parameter, so that it can be checked at compile time, instead of runtime?

> ***NOTE:** If this is possible in `c++03`, then I need the syntax in that form (in case it were to differ from `c++11`).*

#### UPDATE

I arrived at a solution as a derivate of the examples provided by the following SO post...

[C compiler asserts - how to implement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807244/c-compiler-asserts-how-to-implement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### C++11 and above

In C++11 and above there is the [`static_assert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) declaration for this purpose. Your compiler then checks the condition at compile time. You can use it at class scope in the form

```
template <unsigned x>
class myArray {
    static_assert(x > 0 && x <= 64, "array size in (0, 64]");
};
```

### Before C++11

In pre-C++11 there are workarounds to provide the same functionality as C++11's `static_assert`. Most of those workarounds provide a macro based on the following idea: if your check (compile-time expression of type `bool`) yields `false` then the macro expands to some illegal code that produces a compiliation error. Otherwise, the macro expands to an empty string. Advanced implementations allow one to specify an additional error message. If you want an out-of-the-box solution then you may have a look at [`BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/boost_staticassert.html).

Comment: Thank you! I will investigate, and if this solution is what I am looking for, then I will give you the check!