# Compile-time assertion to determine if pointer is an array

Tags: c, assertion

Currently, I have the following block of code to make safe string copying (it works):

```c
#define STRCPY(dst, src) do { assert(((void*)(dst)) == ((void*) & (dst))); \
                              strlcpy(dst, src, sizeof(dst)); } while (0)
```

So it accepts the construction like:

```c
const char *src = "hello";
char dest[5];
STRCPY(dest, src); //hell
```

And denies the following:

```c
void (char *dst) {
    STRCPY(dst, "heaven"); //unknown size of dst
}
```

The problem is that the block of code creates an assertion. Is there a way to perform this check on compilation time?

So I want to have the error on compilation (like [creating an array with negative size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807244/c-compiler-asserts-how-to-implement#809465)) instead of crashing code if it possible.

Comment: `sizeof *dst` is unknown in your case, so what do you expect? And the check _is_  done at compile time. Did you mean: _Is there a way to perform this check on **run** time_?

Comment: a compilation error if a ponter passed (not an array)

Comment: Please [edit]  your question and put all clarifications _there_.

Comment: this not the dup. OP wants to know if the parameter of the macro is pointer or not compile time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For compile-time assertion on whether or not `dst` is an array,
I would use @Lundin solution (or `_Static_assert`) in case C11 is available.

Else, I would use the following:

`#define BUILD_BUG_ON_NON_ARRAY_TYPE(e) (sizeof(struct { int:-!!(((void*)(e)) != ((void*) & (e))); }))`

Which basically takes your compile-time evaluated expression `((void*)(dst)) == ((void*) & (dst))` but instead of using it in run time `assert` just use it in a compile-time assertion manner.

So, overall I would change your macro into:

```
#define STRCPY(dst, src) do { BUILD_BUG_ON_NON_ARRAY_TYPE(dst); \
                              strlcpy(dst, src, sizeof(dst)); } while (0)
```

Answer (score 5):

If standard C is available, then you can do this:

```
#define STRCPY(dst, src)                                        \
  _Generic(&(dst),                                              \
           char(*)[sizeof(dst)]: strlcpy(dst,src,sizeof(dst)) )
```

Explanation:

You can't use a `_Generic` expression on an array type, because it is not one of the special cases that is exempt from the "array decay" rule (C17 6.3.2.1 §3). So by simply using `_Generic((dst), ...` in my example, `dst` would end up as a `char*` when the expression is evaluated, and then we would lose the information of its original type.

But if we take the address of the array using `&`, we do utilize one of those special cases and the array decay doesn't happen. Instead we end up with an array pointer, meaning that `_Generic` will have to check for an array pointer of the expected type and size: `char(*)[sizeof(dst)]`.

---

As a side-note/safety concern, I never use `do-while(0)` macros and discourage them, but that's another story.

Comment: What is the concern with do-while(0) ?  I'm interested in that story :)

Comment: @Michael I wrote a little story about it [here](https://software.codidact.com/questions/279523).

Comment: Thanks.  So '{ ...}' (without do-while ) helps enforce the coding style of 'always use braces'.  (but there are still corner cases like nested 'if-else' as pointed out by 'anatolyg‭'

Answer (score 1):

I've found that my post was closed as duplicated for a while and followed [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19452971/array-size-macro-that-rejects-pointers) mentioned.
The solution is only for GCC, but it's fine for me, because I have night builds on GCC too. So the pre-draft of the code is:

```
#if defined(__GNUC__)
#define BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO(e) (sizeof(struct { int:-!!(e); }))
#define __same_type(a, b) __builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(a), typeof(b))
#define __must_be_array(a) BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO(__same_type((a), &(a)[0]))
#define STRCPY(dst,src) do{__must_be_array(dst);strlcpy(dst, src, sizeof(dst));}while(0)
#else
#define STRCPY(dst,src) do{strlcpy(dst, src, sizeof(dst));}while(0)
#endif
```

Comment: If non-standard gcc is acceptable you should mention this in the question and also tag it with the gcc tag. Anyway, non-standard trickery like this should no longer be necessary since C11. Plus the compiler error from _Generic  is somewhat more readable ("selector of type char** is not compatible with any association") than "could not declare a negative size bit-field" or whatever this macro boils down to.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check it the only way I can think of is:

```
assert((sizeof(dst)) != (sizeof(void*)));
```

but it only work if the size of the array is different than the size of the pointer on OPs system

Comment: This will fail if checked in the scope where the array is passed as pointer which is usually the problematic case.

Comment: @AlexLop. This is not the case here. There is nothing like `passing` in definitions - only replacement.,

Comment: But what you suggest doesn't answers the OP issues. The problem here is that `dst` is a parameter inside a function and it is a pointer. So your assert will always fail it. The point is there is **no way** to check if a pointer is an array.

Comment: @AlexLop. but he asks about the macrodefinition not the function. It is something completely different.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. The OP specifically indicates the case for which his macro doesn't work.

Comment: @P__J__ Thanks, but that's not an answer (I've already thought about comparing size). And sure, I'm looking for a marco, not an assert. So the solution you described should looks something like:

`#define CHECK_ARRAY(dst) do{char x[(sizeof(dst)) == (sizeof(void*))?-1:1];}while(0)`

Solution is not portable and does not work on arrays with the same length as machine word

Comment: @VladimirBotov there is no other way. You need to change your idea.