Compile-time check for -fsingle-precision-constant
I learned from the accepted answer to
Make C floating point literals float (rather than double) and it's discussion,
GCC provides the compiler flag -fsingle-precision-constant to force floating point literals to be single precision instead of the default double precision.
While this may have its pros and cons, is there a way (besides always using f suffix) to ensure that code that is intended to be compiled with -fsingle-precision-constant isn't falsely interpreted?
I came up with this,
int assert_float32_literals[1/(sizeof(float) == sizeof 1.0)];

which (kind of) works:

error: variably modified 'assert_float32_literals' at file scope

But is there a more explicit way with a clear error message?

I think the accepted answer of that question can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807244/c-compiler-asserts-how-to-implement

Tip: sizeof 1.0 == sizeof float avoids non-portable magic values

@IngoLeonhardt That's definitely better than my “solution” but I prefer the answer by user694733.

@ikegami Of course, I was too fast getting it to work somehow. I should better modify this. BTW, In C you need sizeof(float).

@Wolf You may enjoy When does appending an 'f' change the value of a floating constant when assigned to a float?.

@chux-ReinstateMonica Absolutely: this topic is on my to-do list for months.

C11 and above have support for static assertions with a message.
#include <assert.h>
static_assert(sizeof(float) == sizeof 1.0, "Float constants are not correct size");

Or use _Static_assert if you don't want to include assert.h.

In C23, static_assert is a keyword and it is not necessary to include <assert.h> to use it.
