# C++ Getting the size of a type in a macro conditional

Tags: c++, macros, sizeof

Is there some way to do something like this in c++, it seems sizeof cant be used there for some reason?

```
#if sizeof(wchar_t) != 2
#error "wchar_t is expected to be a 16 bit type."
#endif
```

Comment: Learnt that build-time asserts are possible, thanks to your question. This technique is discussed in detail on this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174356/ways-to-assert-expressions-at-build-time-in-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think things like [BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/boost_staticassert.html) could help.

Answer (score 15):

No, this can't be done because all macro expansion (#... things) is done in the pre-processor step which does not know anything about the types of the C++ code and even does not need to know anything about the language!
It just expands/checks the #... things and nothing else!

There are some other common errors, for example:

```
enum XY
{
  MY_CONST = 7,
};

#if MY_CONST == 7
  // This code will NEVER be compiled because the pre-processor does not know anything about your enum!
#endif //
```

You can only access and use things in #if that are defined via command line options to the compiler or via #define.

Comment: Nowadays, the preprosessor doesn't exist sometimes.

Comment: @Cole Johnson: I never see anyone completely omitting the pre-processor. Do you know of any C or C++ compiler without a pre-processor?

Comment: Not that I know of. I was referring to stuff like `#pragma`

Answer (score 8):

The preprocessor works without knowing anything about the types, even the builtin one.

BTW, you can still do the check using a static_assert like feature (boost has one for instance, C++0X will have one).

Edit: C99 and C++0X have also `WCHAR_MIN` and `WCHAR_MAX` macros in `<stdint.h>`

Answer (score 3):

sizeof() is a **<strike>runtime</strike>** compile-time function. You cannot call that in a preprocessor directive. <strike>I don't think you can check the size of wchar_t during preprocessing.</strike> (see Edit 2)

**Edit: As pointed out in comments, sizeof() is *mostly* calculated at compile time. In C99, [it can be used at runtime for arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof).**

**Edit 2: You can do asserts at build time using the techniques described in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174356/ways-to-assert-expressions-at-build-time-in-c).**

Comment: sizeof() is NOT a runtime function. It is a compile-time expression that is evaluated by the compiler on compile-time (but after pre-processor time).

Comment: Thanks, wasn't aware of that. Updated accordingly.

Comment: @nagul: Okay, maybe not always a compile-time expression :-)

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't you get basically what you want (compile error w/o the fancy message) by using a C_ASSERT?

```
#define C_ASSERT(e) typedef char __C_ASSERT__[(e)?1:-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char _assert_wchar_t_is_16bit[ sizeof(wchar_t) == 2 ? 1 : -1];
```

Answer (score 1):

I've developed some macros that will effectively allow you to use sizeof within a macro condition. They're in a header file that I've uploaded [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mgkrupa/MacroSizeof/master/SIZEOF_definitions.h) (MIT license).

It will permit for code like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SIZEOF_definitions.h"

//You can also use SIZEOF_UINT in place of SIZEOF(unsigned, int)
// and UINT_BIT in place of SIZEOF_BIT(unsigned, int)
#if SIZEOF(unsigned, int) == 4
int func() { return SIZEOF_BIT(unsigned, int); }
#elif SIZEOF(unsigned, int) == 8
int func() { return 2 * SIZEOF_BIT(unsigned, int); }
#endif

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  std::cout SIZEOF(unsigned, long, int) << " chars, #bits = " << SIZEOF_BIT(unsigned, long, int) << '\n'
         << SIZEOF(unsigned, int)       << " chars, #bits = " << SIZEOF_BIT(unsigned, int)       << '\n'
         << SIZEOF(int)                 << " chars, #bits = " << SIZEOF_BIT(int)                 << '\n';
  std::cout << func() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Note the commas within `SIZEOF(unsigned, long, int)`.