# How to test if a constant fits into a type while compiling?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, portability

I'd like to add compile time asserts into the following C++ code (compiled with Visual C++ 9):

```
//assumes typedef unsigned char BYTE;
int value = ...;
// Does it fit into BYTE?
if( 0 <= value && value <= UCHAR_MAX ) {
    BYTE asByte = static_cast<BYTE>( value );
    //proceed with byte
} else {
    //proceed with greater values
}
```

The problem is `UCHAR_MAX` and `BYTE` are independent `typedef`s and when this code is ported it can happen that they get out of sync and code will break. So I wanted to do something like this:

```
compileTimeAssert( sizeof( BYTE ) == sizeof( UCHAR_MAX ) );
```

but VC++9 produces "negative subscript" error while compiling that - `sizeof( UCHAR_MAX )` happens to be 4, not 1.

How can I achieve the compile-time check I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test in the compile-time assert that `( (1 << (sizeof(BYTE)*CHAR_BIT)) - 1 ) == UCHAR_MAX`.

(I assume that you're not asking how to do a static assert - there are several ways, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174356/ways-to-assert-expressions-at-build-time-in-c))

Comment: Cool. Should be `CHAR_BIT` instead of 8.

Comment: For `BYTE` this is probably fine, but for larger types won't this overflow?

Answer (score 5):

compare 'value' with std::numeric_limits< BYTE >::max() instead of UCHAR_MAX

Comment: You can't use `std::numeric_limits< BYTE >::max()` in a constant expression, which any static_assert implementation requires. PS I suppose that wasn't really addressing the "static assertion" part of the question.

Comment: True. But static assert is no longer required if you test 'value' against std::numeric_limits< BYTE >::max(). sharptooth wanted to have a static assert only to verify that max value tested against is the correct one for the BYTE type. With numeric_limits, you don't have to worry about that, because it is guaranteed it'll give you the correct max value.

Comment: Ah, yes, you are right, the compile assert is redundant in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Use [BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/boost_staticassert.html).

Answer (score 1):

> but VC++9 produces "negative
>   subscript" error while compiling that
>   - sizeof( UCHAR_MAX ) happens to be 4, not 1.

With this post I am not answering in terms of the solution, but trying to get to the root cause.

Consider the expression

`#define MAX 255;`

My understanding is that `sizeof(MAX) a.k.a (sizeof(255))` is always going to be always the size of the integer literal on the given platform as per the given rules in the Standard 2.3.1/2. Just because it is UCHAR_MAX and holds the max value of a `char` does not mean that the size of such a name will be the size of `char`

> The type of an integer literal depends
>   on its form, value, and suffix. If it
>   is decimal and has no suffix, it has
>   the first of these types in which its
>   value can be represented: int, long
>   int; if the value cannot be
>   represented as a long int, the
>   behavior is undefined. If it is octal
>   or hexadecimal and has no suffix, it
>   has the first of these types in which
>   its value can be represented: int,
>   unsigned int, long int, unsigned long
>   int. If it is suffixed by u or U, its
>   type is the first of these types in
>   which its value can be represented:
>   unsigned int, unsigned long int. If it
>   is suffixed by l or L, its type is the
>   first of these types in which its
>   value can be represented: long int,
>   unsigned long int. If it is suffixed
>   by ul, lu, uL, Lu, Ul, lU, UL, or LU,
>   its type is unsigned long int.

So the expectation of it being `1` needs to be rechecked which seems to the root cause here. `sizeof(MAX)` will be one only on those architectures where `int` is as wide as a `char`. I am not sure how many such systems are really out there.

Answer (score 1):

`UCHAR_MAX` is maximal value of `unsigned char`. Size of `unsigned char` is always 1 byte. If you want to check if range of `BYTE` is `0` .. `UCHAR_MAX` or `-(UCHAR_MAX/2+1)` .. `UCHAR_MAX/2` then simply check if `sizeof(BYTE) == 1`

If you want to check if some int value fits into BYTE then do:

```
if (!(value & ~(BYTE)-1)) ...
```