# Are there any simple ways to check whether a value cannot be safely presented by another type?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, range

As titled.

For example, let's say we have an *int8_t* value "-10", I want to have a dynamic check (runtime value) in my program whether this exact integer value `-10` can be safely held by a *uint32_t* variable after `std::trunc`. And in this case, since this is a negative value, so it CANNOT be held by an unsigned type. How can I do this in C++ code? Since if I use the normal comparison way, the implicit conversion would ruin the typing information like below. Is there any other simple way to do this?

```
  int8_t v = -10; 
  if (v <= std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max() &&
      v >= std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::min()) {
    // It will be true here.
  }
```

I want to find a sound way to check whether the available value range of the target type can totally cover all the available values of the source type. Meaning after the explicit conversion, the result value should be exactly the same as the original one.

Comment: I'd suggest using a library that provides either a wrapper type that handles conversions in the way you want ([`safe_int`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/safe_numerics/doc/html/safe.html) comes to mind) or a checked cast (e.g., `gsl::narrow_cast`). There's definitely prior work out there dedicated to this.

Comment: Negative numbers typically share bit representation in memory with unsigned integers and only the type tells you which it is. Maybe if you use the signed integer limits or some sort of `BigInt` check perhaps this would be ok.

Comment: Converting -10 to `std::uint32_t` is well defined. But if you want to avoid converting negative values to unsigned types, that’s trivial. `if (v < 0) dontdoit;`

Comment: The built-in integer types can't do that, we may also consider use boost.It is more versatile than the libraries mentioned earlier

Comment: First handle the signed/unsigned check seperately - this is easy, check if the value is negative when the target type is unsigned and the source type is signed. If that check succeeds, convert both the value to check and the limits of the target type to the largest integral type available on your platform, and perform that comparison with those extended values, where you can be sure no overflow/underflow would occur.

Comment: duplicates: [Function checking if an integer type can fit a value of possibly different (integer) type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17224256/995714), [How to test if a constant fits into a type while compiling?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3634834/995714), [Checking at compile time if specified value is in a range of a type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5556466/995714), [How to check if value will fit into type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22157923/995714)

Comment: No there isn't. Converting `-10` to an unsigned int is a defined behavior, in other words, in C++ eyes, it is totally allowed. If you want to forbid it, you have to define your own function to tell the machine your own rule.

Answer (score 9):

In C++20 you can use [`std::in_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/in_range)

```
if constexpr (std::in_range<std::uint32_t>(v)) ...
```

See also [Function checking if an integer type can fit a value of possibly different (integer) type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17224256/995714)

---

There's also [intcmp](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/intcmp) to do comparisons yourself

```
if constexpr (std::cmp_greater(v, std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::min())
           && std::cmp_less(v,    std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max()))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Seems not supported by Apple Clang12 even with "-std=c++2a"

Comment: works fine in both gcc and normal Clang https://godbolt.org/z/rPsTMhh96

Comment: @YHSPY Based on cppreference, ***Safe integral comparisons*** is not implemented in Apple Clang yet. In fact, neither Clang libc++ has implemented that.