# parameter check in C macro

Tags: c

I would like to define a macro which will also check limits on its arguments. For example:

```
typedef unsigned char Byte;
#define BQDATA 3
#define MAX_BQ_SIZE (255-BQDATA)

#define BQ(SIZE,NAME)   \
    #if SIZE > MAX_BQ_SIZE \
         #error BQ NAME exceeds maximum size \
    #endif \
    Byte NAME[BQDATA+SIZE+1] = {BQDATA,BQDATA,BQDATA+SIZE}
```

So that if it encounters:

```
BQ(300,bigq);
```

It would flag the error.

Comment: You could implement one of the techniques from the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385515/static-assert-in-c or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174356/ways-to-assert-expressions-at-build-time-in-c. Also, you should *always* put the macro arguments in paranthesis, like `(BQDATA)+(SIZE)+1`, otherwise you'll get problems with operator precedence.

Answer (score 1):

If `size` and `max_bq_size` are compile-time constants you can use `#define BQ(size, name)`[BUILD_BUG_ON](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.2.7/include/linux/kernel.h#L681)`(size > max_bq_size);`. You don't get a custom message, but at least an error.

Comment: That macro is unspeakably hacky. For almost all recent compilers there exist better alternatives.

Comment: Note that BUILD_BUG_ON() will only work inside functions - not for top-level declarations.