# Find out the type of __VA_ARGS__ in a variadic macro

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor, variadic-macros

Supposedly, I have a variadic macro (e.g., `MY_MACRO(...)`) and I call it the following way:

```
MY_MACRO(std::pair<int, int> const &p)
```

Now, `__VA_ARGS__` in my macro's body would be `std::pair<int, int> const &p`.

Is there a way to figure out the type of `__VA_ARGS__`?

Presumably, I would be grateful if something like `decltype(std::pair<int, int> const &p)` worked and yield `std::pair<int, int> const&`, so in my variadic macro's body `decltype(__VA_ARGS__)` would yield `std::pair<int, int> const&` as well. Unfortunately this doesn't work.

Comment: Preprocessor-macros is C++ stuff, like everything else inherited and / or adopted from C.

Comment: @Deduplicator burry the hatchet.

Comment: Macro arguments are arbitrary strings, which needn't be parsable. So speaking of the type of the argument makes little sense.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I know, but I was hoping for some evil sourcery...

Comment: Does the [comma really work in your case?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24793706/1708801)

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: It's a list of two arguments, but that can work with `__VA_ARGS__`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `__VA_ARGS__` as a lambda parameter, then convert that lambda to a function pointer and extract the parameter type:

```
template <typename T> struct func_param {};
template <typename T> struct func_param<void(*)(T)> {using type = T;};

#define FOO(...) \
    do \
    { \
        auto lambda = +[]([[maybe_unused]] __VA_ARGS__) {}; \
        using type = func_param<decltype(lambda)>::type; \
        /* Do something with `type`. */\
    } \
    while (0);
```

Comment: Note using [the fact that lambda w/o capture can be converted to function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28746744/1708801)

Comment: Yes, and also the trick that applying unary `+` to such a lambda forces the conversion, since there is no overloaded `operator+` matching the lambda type, but the pointer to function is a valid operand of the built-in meaning of unary `+`.