# Compile-time assertion fails without GCC optimization

Tags: c, gcc, linux-kernel, macros, gcc-warning

I have following compile-time assertion which fails if I compile without -O[1-3] flags.

```
#ifndef __compiletime_error
#define __compiletime_error(message)
#endif
#ifndef __compiletime_error_fallback
#define __compiletime_error_fallback(condition) do { } while (0)
#endif

#define __compiletime_assert(condition, msg, prefix, suffix)        \
    do {                                \
        int __cond = !(condition);              \
        extern void prefix ## suffix(void) __compiletime_error(msg); \
        if (__cond)                     \
            prefix ## suffix();             \
        __compiletime_error_fallback(__cond);           \
    } while (0)

#define _compiletime_assert(condition, msg, prefix, suffix) \
    __compiletime_assert(condition, msg, prefix, suffix)

#define compiletime_assert(condition, msg) \
    _compiletime_assert(condition, msg, __compiletime_assert_, __LINE__)

#endif
```

This would combine with the following macro which is located in another (gcc-4 specific) file:

```
#define __compiletime_error(message)    __attribute__((error(message)))
```

the issue comes from this line in the code:

```
        extern void prefix ## suffix(void) __compiletime_error(msg); \
```

It seems GCC does not understand `extern` in the macro without `-O[1-3]` flag. I am not sure how should I declare __compiletime_error before it actually gets called in this macro. If I remove this line, I get famous warning of `Implicit declaration of a function`

Comment: Leading underscore(s) `_` are reserved for the toolchain and its headers. You should not use this for your own identifiers.

Comment: @Olaf , you mean I just need to rename `__compiletime_error()` ? I did that and it does not change anything ...

Comment: I did not say it would help here. It was a general note note it _might_ cause  problems. To see wat is going on, inspect the preprocessor output (option `-E`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `compiletime_assert` framework is relying on the optimizer performing dead code elimination to remove the call to `prefix ## suffix`. This is highly fragile and is in no way guaranteed to work.

Instead, try using one of the solutions from [Ways to ASSERT expressions at build time in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174356/ways-to-assert-expressions-at-build-time-in-c) - or, since you're using a modern compiler, just use C11 [`_Static_assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/_Static_assert).