# Ensuring at compile time that all elements of a fixed size array are initialized

Tags: c, arrays

With an array of a specified size, the compiler warns me if I placed too many elements in the initialization:

```
int array[3] = {1,2,3,4}; // Warning
```

But, of course, it doesn't do so if I place too few elements (it just fills them with 0s):

```
int array[3] = {1,2}; //  OK (no warning)
```

Yet, I MUST ensure at compile time that I specify exactly N elements in the initialization of an N-element array (it's an array of function pointers).

Can I have the compiler warn me if I specified too few elements?

Comment: You can omit the number, then use a `static_assert` to check the size ...

Comment: Such as (MSVC) `_STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof arr / sizeof arr[0] == 3);` The man page says "Evaluate an expression at compile time and generate an error when the result is FALSE." But you must omit the array `[length]` as stated above.

Comment: @o11c: That's indeed a nice idea! Why not made that an answer? Does not work if you use designated initialisers and skip some fields, though.

Comment: @WeatherVane: What is `_STATIC_ASSERT`? That is certainly non-standard (and uses a name reserved for the standard itself)

Comment: @Olaf as I wrote, I was showing what MSVC does. It is a [macro](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb918086.aspx). Whatever your opinion is about MSVC, I don't really care.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First define your structure using your parameters, without specifying the size:

```
int array[] = { 1 , 2 , 3 };
```

Then simply check if the size of the created array is the same as N using _Static_assert:

```
_Static_assert( sizeof( array ) / sizeof( array[0] ) == N , "problem with array" );
```

Comment: One should add this requires a standard (i.e. C11) compliant compiler. Which leaves MSVC out (imo no harm done).

Comment: I have GCC v4.5.1. : No _STATIC_ASSERT. Anything else you can think of?

Comment: @DavideAndrea _Static_assert not _STATIC_ASSERT. Just use the C11 mode.

Comment: @2501: IIRC, gcc supports C11 (mostly) with 4.7, fully since4.9 (`stdatomic.h`, but there is a BSD-header available for older versions).

Comment: @DavideAndrea: Updating the compiler is a very good idea. Depending on your platform, great advances have been made not only to language support, but also optimisations.

Comment: @DavideAndrea Static assert can also be implemented manually, it just isn't as pretty: http://stackoverflow.com/q/174356/4082723

Comment: @2501: That will not result in a compile-time warning.

Comment: @Olaf: it did give a compile-time warning

Comment: @DavideAndrea: I should have been more clear: it does give a different warning, possibly missleading. Any reason you refuse to simply update your pretty old version of gcc?

Comment: @Olaf: > refuse to simply update...  - It's not that simple: there are compatibility issues with other programmers. You're right though, that would be best; thanks.