# Is there any compilation of C terminology available on net?

Tags: c

Is there any compilation of C terminology available on net ? I feel it many times difficult to explain in exact technical terms what I wish to say.

Comment: "Terminology" as in "syntax", or "terminology" as in "concepts"?  The answer to both is "yes", but the latter you'd get more from beginner's books than random internet sources.

Comment: This question is inappropriate for StackOverflow. This is not a replacement for a search engine (Google and Bing are both very good at doing that work), nor is it a site to collect links. Voting to close as "not constructive". The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) has more info on the types of questions that fit the design of this site. Keeping questions within site guidelines helps reduce noise and clutter and helps SO remain a useful programming resource.

Comment: @KenWhite I think it's a very useful question for people who want to develop some good amount of understanding in C. What can a person search if he/she does not know how to call it ? I have been trying to learn C from past one year and only now I realize that knowledge of terminology plays a great role in your understanding of some intricate concepts.

Comment: No. It's a requestion for a list of links to off-site locations, which is not what SO is designed to do.

Comment: @KenWhite I think this compilation will be very helpful for the  people at last. I leave it upon members to decide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There really is no substitute for the C Language Standard.  The real deal from ISO is pretty expensive, but you can see a late draft at

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf

The rationale can also be helpful.

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf

Comment: your link is Rationale C99 V2, there is a V5.10 http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf

Comment: and your draft C1X is not the latest one, there is a draft from April 2011, n1570: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf

Answer (score 5):

Here is a compilation:

1. [C Terminology](http://programmingexamples.wikidot.com/c-terminology)
2. [C Reference](http://www.cprogrammingreference.com/Tutorials/Basic_Tutorials/Expressions.php)
3. [Basic C](http://randu.org/tutorials/c/basic.php)
4. [cdecl](http://cdecl.org/)
5. [cprogramming](http://www.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/glossary/glossary.pl)
6. [CLC-wiki](http://clc-wiki.net/wiki/C_language:Terms)<---got from `anon ymous` to add
7. [A to Z](http://www.glenmccl.com/glos.htm)(C++ but there are helpful common terms)
8. [A to Z](http://cplus.about.com/od/c/Glossary_of_Common_Programming_Terms_and_Phrases_C.htm)(C/C++/C#)
9. [wiki-book](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming)
10. [Big tutorial](http://www.iu.hio.no/~mark/CTutorial/CTutorial.html)
11. [Tips and Tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132241/hidden-features-of-c)

Answer (score 3):

Half compiled terminology are available at

- [CLC: terms](http://clc-wiki.net/wiki/C_language%3aTerms)
- [Programming Examples](http://programmingexamples.wikidot.com/c-terminology)

and the best at `3. Terms, definitions, and symbols` of [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf).