# What is the point of switch (...) while (0)?

Tags: c, switch-statement

I recently discovered that `switch (...) while (0) {}` is legal in C ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9220598/14972078)), but I cannot find an explanation about this thing.
The only other time I saw this in the Internet is in an [obfuscation GitHub repository](https://github.com/ColinIanKing/christmas-obfuscated-C/blob/master/tricks/obfuscation-tricks.txt#L155), without any explanation.

All my researches obviously gave me results about while or switch loops, without even mentioning this syntax, so I guess it's more something legal but very rare and likely useless, an abuse of the standard.
Can anyone help me understand this ?

EDIT :
As explained in @phuclv answer, a switch statement expects a selection statement right after, which can be brackets with some code inside (in this case... likely case statements) or a loop with its own brackets etc, it means this is legal in C :

```c
switch (...) while (...) switch (...) {}
```

`switch` doesn't care at all about what statement follows, it only seems to look for case(s) and / or default.

```c
switch (1) while (0) {
    puts("Not executed");
}
```

The `puts` statement isn't executed because there's no case / default, so the switch is basically useless here.
You can see it on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/E1fvdPr5e), GCC gives a warning and removed the switch.

However, beware :

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    switch (1) while (1) switch (0) {
        case 1:
        puts("hello");
    }
}
```

Nothing is displayed and the program is exited instantly, because the switch (1) has no case 1 or default statement.
If we add one :

```c
switch (1) case 1: while (1) switch (0)
```

The program loops indefinitely because the most nested loop is switch (0) with no case 0 or default.

Conclusion : The `while (0)` is only an abuse and has no utility except obfuscation, but that's still an interesting thing to know.

Comment: Are you asking what it does (the link already explains), or why it is allowed?

Comment: There is no real point to this, it just leverages / demonstrates that C's switch is little more than local jumps and doesn't really care about anything else, so you can interleave it with other C syntax. An other demonstration which is actually useful is [Duff's Device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device), but it is more complicated as it actually does thing, so the core insight is less clear.

Comment: Ok I see, I have already seen Duff's device interesting abuse of switch, but here I was wondering if there was any interest other than allow continue in the switch. Also @HolyBlackCat if you know why such thing is legal, I'm listening to you. Does this act lake a while loop inside a switch or is it different ?
Or does it act like a switch taking an one-line statement (as while whithout {}) so the while loop is counted as one instruction belonging to the switch ?

Comment: @Masklinn It's highly questionable if Duff's Device is actually useful in modern programming, it has _not_ aged well.

Comment: Being syntactically valid does not mean that the syntax has a purpose.  That is kind of the point of the answer you referenced in your question.  It is simply "emergent behaviour" of the switch construct syntax definition/implementation.  It happens because it is not explicitly prevented, not because it was intended.  To prevent it would require a more complex language, definition and more complex compiler for no particular benefit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the C standard a statement is defined as one of these

> [A.2.3 Statements](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#A.2.3)
>
> (6.8) statement:
>
> ```
> labeled-statement
> compound-statement
> expression-statement
> selection-statement
> iteration-statement
> jump-statement
> ```

`switch` is a [`selection-statement`](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.4) which is defined to have syntax like this

> (6.8.4) selection-statement:
>
> ```
> if ( expression ) statement
> if ( expression ) statement else statement
> switch ( expression ) statement
> ```

So `switch` receives an `expression` and do the `statement`, which is normally the [`compound-statement` `{}`](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.2) but it can be any statement including the [`iteration-statement`](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.5)

> (6.8.2) compound-statement:
>
> ```
> { block-item-listopt }
> ```
>
> (6.8.5) iteration-statement:
>
> ```
> while ( expression ) statement
> do statement while ( expression ) ;
> for ( expressionopt ; expressionopt ; expressionopt ) statement
> for ( declaration expressionopt ; expressionopt ) statement
> ```

`switch` statement jumps to the [`labeled-statement`](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.1) (which is also a normal statement) and it doesn't care about the content inside the sub statement, the compiler will just generate a computed jump into the `case` matching `expression`

> (6.8.1) labeled-statement:
>
> ```
> identifier : statement
> case constant-expression : statement
> default : statement
> ```

Answer (score 0):

basically, the construction

```
switch(expr) while (cond) {
}
```

should be almost equivalent to:

```
while(cond) {
    switch(expr) {
    }
}
```

except for the order in which `cond` and `expr` are evaluated.

Just check the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    switch(random() % 6) while(1) {
        case 0: printf("You got a one(1)\n");
        case 1: printf("You got a two(2)\n");
        case 2: printf("You got a three(3)\n");
        case 3: printf("You got a four(4)\n");
        case 4: printf("You got a five(5)\n");
        case 5: printf("You got a six(6)\n");
    }
}
```

when run, it gives you something like:

```
You got a four(4)
You got a five(5)
You got a six(6)
You got a one(1)
You got a two(2)
You got a three(3)
You got a four(4)
You got a five(5)
You got a six(6)
You got a one(1)
...
```

### Edit

I'm afraid the output of my post is not actually very random :) So, I'm afraid the equivalence is far from true.

After checking it against the `while(cond) switch(expr)` i got a more or less random sequence, so for some reason the `expr` is not completely evaluated when used the former construct.

After checking it against the `switch(expr) while(cond)` I got no randomness, as the `random()` evaluates only once, and produces the output shown (the first random number happens to be a 0, selecting the first case, and all the others in sequence, looping back to the `while` loop.  In this case, using `break;` in the switch is of no use, as it will break out of the loop making you seen behaviour (the loop executes until the `break;` statement, getting out of the loop)

Comment: I just tried adding break at the end of each case but I don't understand why it runs only once.

Comment: Do you actually need that construction?

Comment: See my edit to the answer, you gave me a hint to answer and to see why the first approach generates some randomness, and the second doesn't. Change the `break;` statement into a `goto end;` (and put an `end` label after the last `case` label), and you will get your desired output.

Comment: I understand better more, that's an interesting case. I'll use a debugger with some codes containing tricky switch to follow their control flow

Comment: probably the best thing is to check what the compiler assembles the code into.  IMHO there's no fair application of putting the `switch` statemente outer to the `while` loop.  The switch seems to evaluate only once... and the next passes select the first case statement.  A bit weird.

Comment: We can see in compiler explorer (https://godbolt.org/z/3dqG5MKrj) that random is in fact called once at the beginning, as you said.